# How create floating button like facebook messenger in C# Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, button, xamarin

I want to create floating button like facebook messenger and when I click on floating button it open activity, but I don't know how to do it. I saw some tutorials for Java but I am using C#. How can I do it in C#? 
Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link can help you

[FAB for Xamarin.Android](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/FloatingActionButton-for-Xamarin.Android)

1) Add the NuGet to your Project: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Refractored.FloatingActionButton/

2) Add the com.refractored.fab.FloatingActionButton to your layout XML file. The button should be placed in the bottom right corner of the screen. The width and height of the floating action button are hardcoded to 56dp for the normal and 40dp for the mini button as specified in the [guidlines].

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.refractored.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_content_new"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/primary"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/primary_pressed"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/ripple" />
```

3) Attach the FAB to AbsListView, RecyclerView or ScrollView :

```
var listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Android.Resource.Id.list);
var fab = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
fab.AttachToListView(listView);
Check the sample project to see how to use custom listeners if you need to track scroll events.
```

4) Add the namespace `xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to your layout file.

Set the button type (normal or mini) via the fab_type xml attribute (default is normal):

```
fab:fab_size="mini"
```

or

```
fab.Size = FabSize.Mini;
```

Set the normal and pressed colors via the xml attributes:

```
fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/primary"
fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/primary_pressed"
```

or

```
fab.ColorNormal = Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.primary);
fab.ColorPressed = Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.primary_pressed);
```

Enable/disable the button shadow with the fab_shadow xml attribite (it's enabled by default):

```
fab:fab_shadow="false"
```

or

```
fab.HasShadow = false;
```

Show/hide the button expliciltly:

```
fab.Show();
fab.Hide();

fab.Show(false); // Show without an animation
fab.Hide(false); // Hide without an animation
```

Specify the ripple color for API 21+:

```
fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/ripple"
```

or

```
fab.ColorRipple = Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.ripple);
```

5) Set an icon for the FloatingActionButton using android:src xml attribute. Use drawables of size 24dp as specified by [guidlines]. Icons of desired size can be generated with [Android Asset Studio].